# What is Homogenous Equation in Partial Differential Equations?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am really confused with all the stuff related to homogenous equations.
Please, anybody, clarify my doubt.

Here is what Homogenous mean to me:

Homogeneous equations are the equations whose order of each of the terms is the same. But what is the fact to do with $RHS=0$. Many sites say $F(D, D') =0$ is a homogenous equation. Finally, how can I identify that the equation is homogenous or non-homogenous? For Example,

$$(2DD'+(D')^2-3D')Z=3\cos(3x-2y)$$
is this homogenous or not?

Comment: This is really a matter of terminology. To me "homogeneous" is the equation which admits the trivial solution $0$. So your equation does not seem to be homogeneous. But this is only my personal interpretation.

Comment: Thank you for your Clarification

Comment: In the frame of ODE's, homogeneous is usually applied to *linear* equations, to express that they have no RHS. (And for this reason admit the null solution, as said by Giuseppe.)

Comment: You must have made some confusion, because $f(D,D')=0$ is not necessarily an homogeneous équation. Counterexample: $D^2D'-4=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homogeneous ODEs are considered because they play an important role in the theory of *linear* equations, via the theorem that says:

The general solution of a linear ODE is the sum of

- the general solution of the homogeneous part of the equation (i.e. dropping the RHS), and
- a particular solution of the non-homogeneous part.

---

To solve $$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x)y^{(k)}(x)=RHS,$$
we write
$$y(x)=y_h(x)+y_{nh}(x)$$

where

$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x)y_h^{(k)}(x)=0$$ and $$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x)y_{nh}^{(k)}(x)=RHS.$$

This decomposition makes sense because usually the homogeneous equation is easier to solve for the general solution. (In particular, homogeneous equations with constant coefficients or of the Cauchy–Euler type have a known analytical solution.)